# How do I stop a count down timer from running when an html link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I have produced this web page for our students, it will open up Internet Explorer in kiosk mode via a bat file on login, once it has opened it will automatically close internet Explorer after 20 seconds. The students also have the option to close the page via a close link on the page.

The issue that I am having is that I want students to be able to stop the countdown timer via a link on the page, so that they can view it for as long as they want.  When they want to close the page they can then use the Close Page link.

I have tried to find a way of stopping the script from running when the Stop Timer link is clicked, but I have not found a way of doing this, also I have little knowledge if JavaScript. It would be helpful if someone could point me in the right direction.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var seconds = 21;

  function startTimer() {
    window.setInterval("updateTime()", 1000);
  }

  function updateTime() {
    --seconds;
    document.getElementById("soFar").innerHTML = seconds;

    if (seconds <= 0) {
      window.open('', '_self').close();
    }
  }
</script>

<body onload="startTimer()">
  <br />
  <br />
  <p>Seconds you have spent viewing this page so far:<strong id="soFar">20</strong>
  </p>
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href="#" onClick="updateTime(); return false;">Stop Timer</a>
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href="javascript:window.open('','_self').close();">close</a>
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href="images/Maths Flash Cards/Slide<?php $random = rand(1,66); echo $random; ?>.JPG" rel="lightbox-maths">
    <br />
    <img src="images/Maths Flash Cards/Slide<?php echo $random; ?>.JPG" alt="" width="327" class="imagezoom" />
  </a>
</body>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just out of interest, for future reference, why is this post being marked down?

Comment: Could be because of "Lack of Research". I didn't vote it down. `:)`

Comment: Searching Google for `stop setinterval` gives you something, which you have obviously missed?

Comment: If you solved the problem, consider to accept an answer or post your own answer to help future users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a variable for `setInterval` like this:

```
var tmr = window.setInterval( "updateTime()", 1000 );
```

And then use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) like below to stop the timer:

```
clearInterval(tmr);
```

The main thing is, make sure that the `tmr` is accessible in both `setInterval` and `clearInterval` scope.

Comment: Hi, I have replaced  `window.setInterval( "updateTime()", 1000 );` with the following  `var tmr = window.setInterval( "updateTime()", 1000 );` and also the line `<a href="#" onClick="updateTime(); return false;">Stop Timer</a>` with `<a href="#" onClick="clearInterval(tmr);">Stop Timer</a>` but is does not work, am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasPowley Awesome. That's right. Can you use a http://jsbin.com or a snippet to show your demo so that we can see where you went wrong?

Comment: Here it is with the changes, I click on the stop timer link and the count down does not stop: 
[http://jsbin.com/reyajevatu/1/edit?html,output]

Comment: @ThomasPowley Remove the `var`. That's what I said you. It works here see: **http://jsbin.com/sofaxanidu/1/edit**

Comment: @ThomasPowley That's the meaning of `The main thing is, make sure that the tmr is accessible in both setInterval and clearInterval scope.`

Comment: Thank you so much it works, I think I understand now.

I had spent a few hours putting all this together, but this was the bit that got me. As I say my understanding of Java script is very little, so thank you.